# Android read SMS messages

Tags: android, sms

I'm trying to build an sms app and the only way I could find to read messages Is `content://sms/inbox`
But I also read that is not recommended to use the specific content provider.

Comment: I am not sure why can't we use the full path to read the messages. I have seen a lot of examples where users use this path only to read through the messages. I don't think there's any harm in using it.

Comment: I'm just looking for reassurance about this